# Automatic snapshot and create an AMI automatically

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have couple of ubuntu based ec2 instances running in the production mode. My problem is when ever the traffic increases I am manually booting the instance update the code from the github.

Now I have to configure the auto scaling, so that whenever the API boots new instance it will boot the latest AMI and attaches to the load balancer, other wise I have to manually pull the code.

To put it more clear here is what I am planning to do.

1. Take periodic snap shot of the instance say on a day to day basis.
2. Create an AMI out of the snap shot and preserve it.
3. While creating a snap shot there should not any downtime.
4. In the auto scaling configuration it should boot the latest AMI and attach it to the load balancer

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of rebuilding an AMI and changing it on a regular basis, build an AMI that automatically pulls from your code repository at boot and maybe periodically after that. This assumes that the only difference in your AMIs would be the code.

For example, if you use SVN you could tag your latest production build with a tag/latest and always pull from that path. Now you have a single AMI that when it boots always has the latest code. You could even go as far as having a cron job run every 5 minutes to look at the tag and revision that is checked out vs what your SVN server is reporting as latest. If that changes, it kills itself and autoscaling starts up replacements; or it just does an svn update and gets the latest changes and keeps chugging.

There is a concern that a build causes your instances to fail to become healthy, but you should be able to catch that in your unit and integration testing.

How to do this? Many options, but using your OS startup scripts is probably best. There are lots of ways to automate access to your code repository. I'm sure there are other StackOverflow questions regarding that.

Comment: If the webserver starts automatically, your ELB node health check could include a check to make sure the code has been updated.